# ¿Puede R, manejar signos de moneda y separadores de miles?

Tags: r, rstudio, importación

¡Muy buenas a todos compañeros! Me presento, soy Saúl y soy novato en R y RStudio.

De lo que he buscado, no es lo más apropiado usar signos y separadores en los números al usar R, lo que me causa la siguiente duda: ¿Con R, sólo se debe usar números enteros y flotantes?

Verán todo esto debido al siguiente problema:

Estoy trabajando con un marco de datos proveniente de un archivo ***.txt***, y estoy realizando la limpieza y formateo. Ya cambie nombres, por aquello de la privacidad. Sin embargo, tengo dos variables numéricas con las que no puedo avanzar.

Al ejecutar la función str() marca lo siguiente:

> $ TC : chr  "947" "614" "514" "615" ...

> $ TA: chr  " $4,502,123.00 " " $2,992,021.00 " " $2,637,641.00 " " $3,172,748.00 " ...

Quiero convertir la variable a números enteros y entero flotante (por los decimales). Decidí usar un mutate:

```
Data_Ch %>% mutate(TC = as.numeric(TC), TA = as.numeric(TA))
```

Sin embargo, me salta el siguiente error (Para ambas variables, pero sólo coloco ejemplo de una):

> Problem while computing `TC = as.numeric(TC)`. ℹ NAs introduced by coerción

Ya lo intente como ***“as.integer”***, pero sigue el mismo error. Yo me supongo, que por el uso de comas, sigo de pesos, y signo de comillas, es que no puedo convertirlos.

Entonces, lo siguiente es eliminar comillas, signo de pesos, y las comas. Pero ahí me surgió la duda: a la hora de graficar, sólo se verán los números sin formato alguno? Yo vengo de ***excel***, entonces me disculparan por dudas tan obvias.

Si pudiesen orientar sobre que camino seguir en mi auto enseñanza en R, estaría muy agradecido.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido Itzu a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Esto:

```
$ TA: chr " $4,502,123.00 " " $2,992,021.00 " " $2,637,641.00 " " $3,172,748.00 "
```

Te dice dos cosas, por un lado la variable claramente no es numérica, sino una cadena y por el otro, el formato de la misma no es "convertible" a un numérico, no al menos de forma automática.

Una forma bien sencilla, es importar los datos y hacer un proceso posterior para eliminar el `$` y la `,`:

```
cadenas <- c(" $4,502,123.00 ", " $2,992,021.00 ", " $2,637,641.00 ",
             " $3,172,748.00 ") 

as.numeric(gsub('[$|,]','', cadenas))

[1] 4502123 2992021 2637641 3172748
```

Con `gsub()` y el patrón regular `[$|,]` tanto el `$` o la `,` serán eliminadas de las cadenas y ahora sí, estas serán convertibles a un número.

En tu código podrías implementar algo así:

```
Data_Ch %>% 
  mutate(TC = as.numeric(gsub('[$|,]','',TC)), 
         TA = as.numeric(gsub('[$|,]','',TA))
  )
```

También, mucho mejor aún, podría ser, configurar un formato de importación, para que la conversión se haga directamente en esta instancia, pero no sé como estás importando los datos.